# How to generate next sequence value with in my insert statement in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

If its in my sql server procedure means, I assign like following for particular table:

**select @id=NEXT value FOR sq_id;**

Now for same sequence value I need to do and insert some other column values also for a particular table using spring-hibernate
So I need the insert query with generate next sequence value for a particular table..!

Comment: You don't... Hibernate takes care of that for you... Specify the field which represents the ID and use the proper annotations on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use create sequence in sql server:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.TestSequence
START WITH 1  
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

For next value we can use 
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence

We can make cylic sequence, any increments any starting point or ending point etc.,